# Ошибка при выделении памяти в классе

Tags: c++, массивы, память

Для динамического выделения памяти использую два массива: array и copy. copy принимает значения массива array, затем я переопределяю размерность array и возвращаю в него родные значения из copy. Метод add(string) добавляет значения в массив array, но работает до тех пор, пока не добавляется пятый элемент (ругается на память).

```
class massiv
{
private:
int size;
string* array;
string* copy;

public:
massiv()
{
    cout << "constr\n\n";
    size = 1;
    array = new string[size];
}

~massiv()
{
    cout << "\ndestr\n";
    delete [] array;
}

void add(string text)
{
    array[size-1] = text;
    size++;

    copy = new string[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        copy[i] = array[i];
    delete [] array;

    array = new string[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        array[i] = copy[i];
    delete [] copy;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
massiv first;

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){ //если поставить i<4 - корректно работает, если больше - вылетает
    first.add("success");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поясните  что, где и как ругается?

Comment: @Cerbo  В моем доме попрошу не выражаться!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Не понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `add` некорректная. При входе в функцию массив `array` имеет `size-1` элементов. Однако после присваивания новой строки, вы объект `size` увеличиваете

```
void add(string text)
{
    array[size-1] = text;
    size++;
    ^^^^^^^
    //...
```

Например, до вызова функции массив `array` имел 0 элементов и `size` равнялось 1. Теперь же после выполнения первых двух предложений функции `size` равно 2, а массив `array`  имеет всего лишь один элемент с индексом 0.

Затем вы создаете массив `copy` с новым увеличенным значением `size` и это же значение используете в цикле, хотя элемента с индексом `size-1` (для вышеуказанного примера это выражение для индекса будет равно 1) не существует

```
copy = new string[size];
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    copy[i] = array[i];
//...
```

Вам надо использовать здесь значение `size-1` вместо `size`

Например,

```
void add( const string &text )
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
{
    array[size-1] = text;
    int new_size = size + 1;

    copy = new string[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        copy[i] = array[i];
    delete [] array;

    array = new string[new_size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        array[i] = copy[i];
    delete [] copy;

    size = new_size;
}
```

И нет никакой необходимости объявлять как член класса указатель `copy`, который используется только как временная переменная в функции `add`.

И было бы лучше использовать стандартный класс `std::vector<std::string>` вместо того, чтобы вручную самому управлять выделением памяти.

Answer (score 0):

```
array[size-1] = text;
size++;    // размер наростили

copy = new string[size];
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    copy[i] = array[i];   // а array то прежним остался
delete [] array;
```

Вот так правильно

```
void add(string text)
{
   copy = new string[size + 1];    // создаем новый увеличенный массив
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       copy[i] = array[i];         // копируем старое
   }
   copy[size] = text;              // добавляем новый элемент
   size++;                         // увеличиваем размер

   delete [] array;                // удаляем старый массив
   array = copy;                   // просто копируем указатель

   copy = nullptr;                 // зануляем для порядка
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно не заметил. Получается, "delete [] copy" равнозначно "copy = nullptr"?

Comment: @DenisPetrov: Нет. `delete[] copy` освобождает память. При этом значение `copy` не меняется. А `copy = nullptr` затирает указатель на память. При это если вы раньше не освободили память, то вы уже не сможете её освободить, значения указателя у вас больше нет.